# Preencher um campo texto e aparecer o mesmo texto em outro campo

Tags: javascript

Tenho três campos textos contendo as seguintes informações: Nome, Email e Telefone. Como eu faria para que ao preencher um dos campos, as mesmas informações aparecessem no outro campo?

Igual o que ocorre aqui quando digitamos nossas dúvidas. O texto que digitamos aparece logo abaixo automaticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar angular para isto.

basta adicionar o script na head do seu site :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

e para fazer o que você esta querendo basta fazer o seguinte:

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS - Tableless</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" ng-model="nome">
        <p>Olá, Meu nome é: {{ nome }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giancarlodebian/bke4q4nt/)**

> Lembrando que dependendo do código javascript que você usar, como eventos de quando as teclas são pressionadas isso pode não funcionar em dispositivos móveis. Por isso aconselho usar AngularJS

Comment: Você vai sugerir pro cara incluir o angular todo somente pra fazer isso ?

Comment: Mas você recomenda solucionar o problema dele de que maneira? Obs: De forma pratica e com código limpo.

Comment: Com javascript puro, pois é um problema muito simples.

Comment: Só acho que não tem porque não usar um Framework como AngularJs que resolve o problema de uma forma tão simples e organizada para fazer códigos js puro.

Comment: SE o OP já usar angular no sistema dele obviamente seria o correto, mas acho que não é o caso. Então incluir uma lib inteira que faz muito mais do que manipular o DOM **apenas** pra manipular o DOM não seria coerente.

Answer (score 5):

Isso é mais ou menos simples de fazer. Precisas adicionar um oscultador de eventos para correr uma função quando o evento `keyup` fôr chamado. Aí passas o valor do input para dentro da div, ou outro elemento que tenhas.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    div.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

Isto é feito no Browser, sem recurso a nada no lado do servidor via ajax.

#### jsFidde: http://jsfiddle.net/x5vwp6uo/

Comment: Boa resposta. Poderia adicionar uma explicação sobre isso não ser ajax, já que o OP incluiu a tag na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, uma maneira bem fácil de se fazer isso é utilizando a metodologia de data binding.

Existem muitos frameworks leves e fáceis de usar para isso, por exemplo o [Ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/)

Se quiser exemplos eu posto aqui, mas vou mostrar como fazer isso utilizando apenas com javascript mesmo.

```
var meuCampo = document.querySelector('input');

var paragrafo = document.querySelector('p');

meuCampo.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    paragrafo.innerHTML = meuCampo.value;
});
```

Veja que isso não tem nada haver com AJAX. AJAX é uma metodologia de requisição (padrão de request e response) de solicitar uma informação a um servidor, api, webservice ou qualquer coisa do tipo e se obter uma resposta sem "travar" o uso da página, ou seja uma realizar uma requisição assíncrona.

Mais sobre ajax [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).