# Conforme for preenchendo os campos, os dados aparecerem automaticamente em uma div

Tags: jquery

É o seguinte. Tenho um formulário onde contém: Nome, Idade, Gênero e Cidade. Gostaria de que o usuário conforme fosse preenchendo esse formulário, os dados aparecessem em uma outra div automaticamente. O mesmo que ocorre aqui, quando digitamos, aparece abaixo os dados digitados.

Obrigado

Comment: Vocês me desculpem. Eu já havia feito essa pergunta antes aqui e esqueci completamente. Não vou apagar o post, mas disponibilizar a resposta no outro post caso alguém precise. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87259/preencher-um-campo-texto-e-aparecer-o-mesmo-texto-em-outro-campo

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Preencher um campo texto e aparecer o mesmo texto em outro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87259/preencher-um-campo-texto-e-aparecer-o-mesmo-texto-em-outro-campo)

Comment: Olá Pessoal. Só sugiro para não fecharem o tópico, pois a pergunta que fiz no outro post foi há 02 anos. Acredito que mantê-lo ativo, pode ajudar as pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida hoje em dia.

Comment: O tópico pode ser fechado por ser duplicata, mas não será excluído.

Comment: Combinado dvd..